# jsoup post login is not being redicted

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

I am having issues trying to log using the jsoup to log in. I am not sure if this one has any cookies? Am I missing something? why can't i log in?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class LoginJtest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Connect to page and parse html into a 'Document'


        //This will get you the response.
        Response res = Jsoup
            .connect("https://pslweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/login.jsp")
            .data("txtUserName", "myusername", "txtPassword", "mypassword")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

        //This will get you cookies
        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

        //And this is the easiest way I've found to remain in session
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pslweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/")
              .cookies(loginCookies)
              .get();
           String title = doc.title();
       System.out.println(title);


    }
}
```

This is the the source of the website for the login I am trying to access.

```
<div class="loginPanel">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Login</div>
    <form id="loginForm" class="loginForm" method="POST" action="/dis/login">
        <font class="portlet-msg-error"
         style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></font>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">USERNAME:</td>
            <td><input
                value=""
                class="edit"
                id="txtUsernameLogin"
                name="txtUserName"
                type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">PASSWORD:</td>
            <td><input
                value=""
                class="edit"
                name="txtPassword"
                type="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="txtRemember" value="true" align="middle"/>
            Remember me on this computer
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class=""><input type="submit"
                    class="submit"
                    value="Login"
                    alt="Login"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you facing problems in log-in to the system or expecting any redirection after log-in? Your question and the subject are contradictory. If you are unable to log-in then what is the `Response ` you are receiving, Did you try cross checking the output of the action with `Browser vs Jsoup`. Just check the output in `Chrome Browser's`  `Network Tab` and Jsoup Output.

Comment: I am not being able to get redirected after log in, it displays the same output title from the login page. The title from the page i am suppose to get redirected is "All devices" and I get "login". I also try adding the .useragent to chrome and mozilla and same result doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are posting to /dis/login.jsp whereas the form posts to /dis/login

It also may be because of security features employed by the website. Try setting a referrer, user-agent, etc in Jsoup.

Comment: what do you mean by "try setting a referrer"? I added  the userAgent to the response and it did not work for me
 .userAgent("Mozilla")

Comment: Adding a [referrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) can be done by using .referrer(String url). And have you tried changing the post url?